# Where and how to add CSS in a Dynamic Web Project in Eclipse?

Tags: html, css, eclipse, jsp

I tried a normal test project to check if CSS is applying to the JSP page. But, no matter where I put my css file in the hierarchy, it is not working.
Where to place the css file and how to include the tag in JSP?

[this is my Project hierarchy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IvpKs.png)

I wrote a simple

```
    <link href="css/grayscale.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

to include css file.

my css file only consists of a test style to change paragraph style.

Please Help :(

Answer (score 1):

In the same location of your JSP file, create a CSS directory (named css) in which you create your CSS file. To access it try using "/css/grayscale.css"

Comment: Try ../css/grayscale.css

Comment: Nope :/
Is there anything I should add in my dispatcher servlet?

Comment: I don't see any relation between the dispatcher servlet and the css, but it may be the cause...